# mvc timespan or something similar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have used `TimeSpan control` in my windows app C# that allows the user to enter the remaining time. And it would show, Hrs, Mins, Secs and once the time expires it would execute a method.

I want to do similar idea in MVC Razor, but not sure how to add the `TimeSpan control`/or something similar in MVC and show it in the view.

How do I loop in the view or in control so it dynamically shows the remaining hrs, mins, sec in the view?

Please point me to an example if you know

My goal is to show remaining time like [dealfind.com](http://www.dealfind.com/kitchener-waterloo/)

Comment: Web development is not like WinForms.  You need to learn Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). It has an expiration callback (amongst others). jQuery is bundled with ASP.NET MVC 3.